# How to solve for $t$ using $\arctan(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

**Context:** I solved the following simple nonhomogeneous equation: $y''-3y'-4y=2 \sin (t)$.

We assumed that $Y(t)=A\sin(t)$, where $A$ was to be determined.

Now, $Y'(t)=A\cos(t)$ and $Y''(t)=-A\sin(t)$; thus, plugging the derivatives in the original equation we had
$$
[-A\sin(t)-3A\cos(t)-4A\sin(t)]=2\sin(t)
$$ 
or 
$$
(2+5A)\sin(t)+3A\cos(t)=0.
$$

We want the last equation to hold for all $t$. It does make sense to me that it holds only if $t=0$ and $t=\pi/2$, in which case the equation reduces to $3A=0$ and $(2+5A)=0$; however, I am unsure how these specific values have been found in this last step.

How do I find values for $t$ that satisfy my last equation using $\arctan(t)$?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you already found the homogeneous solution. Assume $y_p(t) = a \cos t + b \sin t$. You should find $a = \dfrac{3}{17}$ and $b = -\dfrac{5}{17}$.

Comment: As Amzoti stated above, you have chosen the wrong ansatz.

Comment: Yes you can not only assume that it will contain a $\sin\left(x\right)$, you could use the method of undetermined coefficients to solve, but part of that is assuming the particular solution is composed of both parts.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear, Yes i have found the solution and the values you just mentioned in your post,i just want to know whether my last equation holds with $t=0$ and $t=\pi/2$ just because it makes sense when we look at the graphs or there is a way of finding these two values (solving for t)?

Comment: Start over with the guess $y = A \cos t + B \sin t$. Repeat the same steps, you will find you need $-5A -3B = 0, 3A -5B = 2$, which has the solution given above.

Comment: I think one can find other values of $A$ and $t$ such that $(2+5A)\sin t+3A\cos t=0$. Just use the addition law for sine. But it is easy to see that there is no choice of $A$ for which the equation holds for all $t$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry for bringing this up once again, but i was told that in order to find values for $t$ that satisfy the equation $(2+5A)sin(t)+3Acos(t)=0$ i have to use $arctan(t)$ ... Any ideas how to go about it?

Comment: For general $(2+5A)\sin t+3A\cos t=k$, we use the addition law for sine. In the special case $k=0$, the equation can be rewritten as $(2+5A)\sint t=-3A \cos t$, and then by dividing both sides by $(2+5A)\cos t$ as $\tan t=-\frac{3A}{2+5A}$. In general there are two solutions of this in the interval $[0,2\pi)$, and yes, they can be expressed in terms of $\arctan$.

Comment: (More) Assume $2+5A\ne 0$. We are solving the equation $\tan t=C$, where $C=-\frac{3A}{2+5A}$. The solution in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is, by definition, $\arctan C$. There are infinitely many solutions, given by $t=\arctan C+n\pi$,, where $n$ ranges over the integers.  Note that the problem solved in these last two comments has not much connection with solving the DE.